# Split DataFrame string column into N splits

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, split

i have a df

```
a    name
1    a/b/c
2    w/x/y/z
3    q/w/e/r/t
```

i want to split the name column on '/' to get this output

```
id    name    main    sub    leaf
1     a/b/c    a       b       c
2    w/x/y/z   w       x       z
3   q/w/e/r/t  q       w       t
```

i.e first two slashes add as **main** and **sub** respectively,
and leaf should be filled with word after last slash

i tried using this, but result was incorrect

```
df['name'].str.split('/', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'main',1:'sub',2:'leaf'})
```

is there any way to assign columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
Using `str.split`, but don't expand the result. You should end up with a column of lists. Next, use `df.assign`, assign columns to return a new DataFrame object.

```
v = df['name'].str.split('/')

df.assign(
    main=v.str[ 0],
     sub=v.str[ 1],
    leaf=v.str[-1]
)

        name leaf main sub
a                         
1      a/b/c    c    a   b
2    w/x/y/z    z    w   x
3  q/w/e/r/t    t    q   w
```

*Details*
This is what `v` looks like:

```
a
1          [a, b, c]
2       [w, x, y, z]
3    [q, w, e, r, t]
Name: name, dtype: object
```

This is actually a lot easier to handle, because you have greater control over elements with the `.str` accessor. If you expand the result, you have to snap your ragged data to a tabular format to fit into a new DataFrame object, thereby introducing `None`s. At that point, indexing (finding the ith or ith-last element) becomes a chore.

---

**Option 2**
Using direct assignment (to maintain order) -

```
df['main'] = v.str[ 0]
df['sub' ] = v.str[ 1]
df['leaf'] = v.str[-1]

df    
        name main sub leaf
a                         
1      a/b/c    a   b    c
2    w/x/y/z    w   x    z
3  q/w/e/r/t    q   w    t
```

Note that this modifies the original dataframe, instead of returning a new one, so it is cheaper. However, it is more intractable if you have a large number of columns.

You might instead consider this alternative which should generalise to many more columns:

```
for c, i in [('main', 0), ('sub', 1), ('leaf', -1)]:
    df[c] = v[i]

df
        name main sub leaf
a                         
1      a/b/c    a   b    c
2    w/x/y/z    w   x    z
3  q/w/e/r/t    q   w    t
```

Iterate over a list of tuples. The first element in a tuple is the column name, and the second is the corresponding index to pick the result from `v`. You still have to assign each one separately, whether you like it or not. Using a loop would probably be a clean way of doing it.

Comment: @you're both just too fast!

Comment: @josh They don't call me cold _speed_ for nothing. ;)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Haha ! exactly! :)

Comment: @SRingne I have seen jezrael answering questions all day, and quite frankly I felt like making him sweat for a question or two. The votes count somehow tells me what happens next... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
s = df['name'].str.split('/')
df = df.assign(main=s.str[0], sub=s.str[1], leaf=s.str[-1])
print (df)
   a       name leaf main sub
0  1      a/b/c    c    a   b
1  2    w/x/y/z    z    w   x
2  3  q/w/e/r/t    t    q   w
```

For change order of columns:

```
s = df['name'].str.split('/')
df = df.assign(main=s.str[0], sub=s.str[1], leaf=s.str[-1])
df = df[df.columns[:-3].tolist() + ['main','sub','leaf']]
print (df)
   a       name main sub leaf
0  1      a/b/c    a   b    c
1  2    w/x/y/z    w   x    z
2  3  q/w/e/r/t    q   w    t
```

Or:

```
s = df['name'].str.split('/')
df = (df.join(pd.DataFrame({'main':s.str[0], 'sub':s.str[1], 'leaf':s.str[-1]}, 
              columns=['main','sub','leaf'])))
print (df)
   a       name main sub leaf
0  1      a/b/c    a   b    c
1  2    w/x/y/z    w   x    z
2  3  q/w/e/r/t    q   w    t
```

Comment: @you're both just too fast!

Comment: @josh exactly, too fast too furious :p